# Where are my latex fonts (linux)

Tags: fonts, gnuplot

I am pretty sure this question was already asked but I cannot find it.
I am using ubuntu and would like to know where are the font files I am using when I compile a latex document? 
I looked at them using my PDF reader (okular) but it does not tell me where the original file is and moreover, the name are strange, for example: WMZQAI+CMR12.
I would like to use these fonts in gnuplot without downloading anything and just use the ones that are on my computer.
Thanks

Comment: The strange names are due to *subsetting*. That is, rather than embedding entire fonts, TeX embeds just those parts which are needed to display your document. If you use `microtype`, they may also represent expanded variants of the fonts used, for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For LaTeX all of your fonts (*.pfb, *.map, ...) are in `$TEXMF/fonts` or `$TEXMFLOCAL/fonts` or in 
`$TEXMFHOME/fonts`. The style and fd (font definition) files are always under `$TEXMF/tex/latex/`

For Xe(La)TeX and Lua(La)TeX also in the systems font directories: `/usr/share/fonts`, `/usr/local/share/fonts/` and `~/.fonts/`. However, for Xe(La)TeX you have to modify the search path for fontconfig. Otherwise the fonts in the TeX-distribution are not found. Lua(La)TeX has its own font search handling.

Comment: It might be worth a mention that you can get a start on figuring out what these are with kpsewhich, for example as in kpsewhich -expand-path='$TEXMF/fonts' (the single quotes matter).

Comment: Thank you for kpsewhich answer, I didn't know this

Comment: For LaTeX all of your fonts ... -> For TeX all of your fonts ... (LaTeX is irrelevant here). For XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX also ... -> For XeTeX and LuaTeX also ... (LaTeX is only macro package).

Comment: It is _not_ irrelevat! LaTeX font handling is far different to TeX font handling. For the font file itself it is relevant, but not for all the other auxiliary font files.